# How to display first ViewController values in Second ViewController tableview with Model in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, variables, model, pushviewcontroller

I have created address model with NSObject. in first view controller i have button to push second viewcontroller.

Address Model look like this:

```
 class ProfileModelUserAddress : NSObject, NSCoding{
var pincode : String!
var city : String!
var streetName : String!

init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
    pincode = dictionary["pincode"] as? String
    city = dictionary["city"] as? String
    streetName = dictionary["streetName"] as? String
}

func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
{
    var dictionary = [String:Any]()

    if pincode != nil{
        dictionary["pincode"] = pincode
    }
    if city != nil{
        dictionary["city"] = city
    }
    if streetName != nil{
        dictionary["streetName"] = streetName
    }
    return dictionary
}

@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    pincode = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "pincode") as? String
    city = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "city") as? String
    streetName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "streetName") as? String
}

@objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    if pincode != nil{
        aCoder.encode(pincode, forKey: "pincode")
    }
    if city != nil{
        aCoder.encode(city, forKey: "city")
    }
    if streetName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(streetName, forKey: "streetName")
    }
}
}
```

**in first view controller how to add below values to model to display in second viewcontroller table view:**

```
self.localityName = placemark.locality ?? ""
self.sublocalityName = placemark.subLocality ?? ""
self.zipName = placemark.postalCode ?? ""
```

**In second view controller how to display first view controller values in table view and its count**

```
var addressModel: ProfileModelUserAddress?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return modeladdress.count // here how to add count
 }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell: EditAddressTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell") as! EditAddressTableViewCell
     let addr = addressModel.[indexPath.row]
     let street = addr?.streetName
     city   = addr?.city
     pincode = addr?.pincode

     cell.addressLabel.text = "\(city!) \(pincode!) \(street)"
     print("add address tableview cll \(cell.addressLabel.text)")
     return cell
 }
```

Edit:

**if i add like below answer city, pincode, etc.. like every field coming seperatley like below: i need all fields in `cell.addressLabel.text` this label**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to use a single `String` for each row then, here's how:

```
class SecondViewController: UITableViewController {

    var addressModelArray = [ProfileModelUserAddress]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        addressModelArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: EditAddressTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell") as! EditAddressTableViewCell
        let addressModel = addressModelArray[indexPath.row]
        var text = addressModel?.locality ?? ""
        text.append(addressModel?.subLocality ?? "")
        text.append(addressModel?.postalCode ?? "")
        cell.textLabel.text = text
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: if i append like `addressModelArray.append(addressModel?.postalCode ?? "")`  each field comig separately in row in tabelview.. added tableview image in questio.. i need pincode, sublocality, localitey nema in `cell.textLabel.text` this lable

Comment: You mean you need all the texts in 1 single cell?

Comment: yes pls share that code........ i need entaire text in one cell..

Comment: For that, you just need to append the strings to the first element of the array.

Comment: not 1 row, its a tableview so there will be number of address rows.. if i select another address then how? i need to show any number of address in tableview